# Renaming a single plot i a sequence of 5 plots

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have the 5 plots generated by the code below. What i need is a quick way to only rename the title of the 3th plot from dataset(100,33) to dataset-trial.  Whats the fasted way to do that?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ratios = [(100, 2), (100, 20),(100,33),(100, 40), (100, 80)]
plt.figure(figsize = (20,6))
for j,i in enumerate(ratios):
  plt.subplot(1, 5, j+1) 
  X_p=np.random.normal(0,0.05,size=(i[0],2))
  X_n=np.random.normal(0.13,0.02,size=(i[1],2))
  y_p=np.array([1]*i[0]).reshape(-1,1)
  y_n=np.array([0]*i[1]).reshape(-1,1)
  X=np.vstack((X_p,X_n))
  y=np.vstack((y_p,y_n))
  plt.title("dataset" + str(j+1) +str(i))
  plt.scatter(X_p[:,0],X_p[:,1])
  plt.scatter(X_n[:,0],X_n[:,1],color='red')
plt.show()
```

Thanks

Comment: [OOP instead of pyplot](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html)

Comment: you're using `enumerate`, so `if j == 2: ...`

Comment: `plt.gcf().axes[2].set_title("Third subplot")` would work (but isn't the recommended approach)